# Django - get object by id and clone it

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I tried to clone model instance object and save it to the database on this way:

`some_object = ModelName.objects.get(id=1)
some_object.id = None
some.object.save()`

But in `ModelName` i have **ManyToMany** relation with another model and after saving i didn't get data from another model. How is possible to solve this?

Comment: The many-to-many relations are *not* copied: these are stored in a separate (hidden) table.

Comment: You'll need to re-associate the many to many relation with the cloned object, and then save.